# I added the javax.mail, but it keeps saying the class does not exist

Tags: java, email, netbeans, jakarta-mail

Here's the thing: I've downloaded the javax.mail API, added it under Libraries->Add Jar/Folder. I've compiled the code, but it keeps yielding an error on the 'import javax.mail;' sentence, saying that the package does not exist. What is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Check the two JAR files(mail.jar and activation.jar) file in your project library. Make sure to put the JAR file not ZIP file in correct folder

Comment: I've extracted the javax.mail JAR file to the netbeans8.0.2  folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned this line:

```
import javax.mail;
```

This won't work, because `mail` is a package and not a class. Either use:

```
import javax.mail.*;
```

to import the whole package or import specific classes using:

```
import javax.mail.Header;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
```

(the classes are randomly selected and should only show how to import a specific class)

Answer (score 0):

you commented

> I've extracted the javax.mail JAR file to the netbeans8.0.2 folder

you dont need to do that,
it should be enough to put the jar in your project's lib folder and maybe reference it in the build path.
cheers

Comment: What I meant was that I've exctracted the javax.mail JAR file FROM the zip file. My bad..